# How to center a IMG tag horizontaly and vertically using html and css in ie7?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I put 'a' tag in my html and add position relative to it then append 'img' tag in 'a' tag and add absolute position, left 0, right 0, top 0, bottom 0, margin auto to 'img' tag.

this code not working in ie7. In other browser it works fine.

whats wrong in my code?

I create code as follow:

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="img-link-wrap"><img alt="Image 1" src="img/501.jpg"></a>
```

CSS:

```
a.img-link-wrap {
border: 1px solid #999;
display: block;
position: relative;
height: 11em;
width: 10em;
text-align: center;
}

a.img-link-wrap img {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
}
```

Thanking You.

Comment: Not exactly sure what youre trying to achieve here. Do you want the 'a' tag to be taller and wider than the image within it and then have it centered horizontally and vertically within the 'a' tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to center an element, use this code snippet:

```
.centered {
  position: based on your choice;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -(element_height/2);
  margin-left: -(element_width/2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about it's working but try to add `overflow: hidden;` to the style of `a` tag